# UITableView: Load data from array after viewDidLoad()

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to load the items of an array into a UITableView in a Swift iOS App.

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let website = MyWebsite()
    let authenticated = ViewAuthenticated()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func getData(_ sender: Any) {
        var arrayTEST = self.website.getArray() //["red", "green", "blue"]
        self.authenticated.data = arrayTEST //["red", "green", "blue"]
        let viewAuth = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewAuthenticated") as! ViewAuthenticated
        self.present(viewAuth, animated: true)
    }

}
```

**ViewAuthenticated.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewAuthenticated: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    public var data: [String] = ["123", "456", "789"]

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellReuseIdentifier")!
        let text = data[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = text
        return cell
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


}
```

What I would like to do is creating a UITableView containing the items sent by ViewController.
I think the problem is that in ViewAuthenticated the UITableView is created before ViewController sends his new array (["red", "green", "blue"]).
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the array of values to data property of ViewAuthenticated View, before presenting the view.

```
@IBAction func getData(_ sender: Any) {
        var arrayTEST = self.website.getArray() //["red", "green", "blue"]
        self.authenticated.data = arrayTEST //["red", "green", "blue"]
        let viewAuth = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewAuthenticated") as! ViewAuthenticated
        viewAuth.data = self.authenticated.data
        self.present(viewAuth, animated: true)
    }
```

And remove the hardcoded data array value. Change it to :

```
var data: [String] = []
```

Comment: It's pretty weird to create a *dummy* temporary view controller – which will never be used again – and assign the array to this controller. Then instantiate the *real* view controller and copy the data from the dummy controller to the real controller. OMG.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution, the `authenticated` controller is not needed at all:

<strike>`let authenticated = ViewAuthenticated()`</strike>

...

```
@IBAction func getData(_ sender: Any) {
    let viewAuth = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewAuthenticated") as! ViewAuthenticated
    viewAuth.data = self.website.getArray() //["red", "green", "blue"]
    self.present(viewAuth, animated: true)
}
```